# How to combine two projects in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I have two separate mercurial repositories. At this point it makes sense that they "become one" because I want to work on the two projects simultaneously.

I'd really like the two projects to each be a subdirectory in the new repository.

1. How do I merge the two projects?
2. Is this a good idea, or should I
   keep them separate?

It seems I ought to be able to push from one repository to the other... Maybe this is really straight forward?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I was able to combine my two repositories in this way:

1. Use `hg clone first_repository` to clone one of the repositories.
2. Use `hg pull -f other_repository` to pull the code in from the other repository.

The `-f` (force) flag on the pull is the key -- it says to ignore the fact that the two repositories are not from the same source.

Here are [the docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergingUnrelatedRepositories) for this feature.

Comment: Does this preserve the commits' hash keys from the second repo too? (I'd guess not, but it might be ok until you do a merge.)

Comment: This works, but you'll need to also run `hg merge` to finally get everything working

Comment: **@Marcus Lindblom:** pulling a changeset will never, *ever* change its hash.  If you look at `hg glog` after doing this you'll see you have two unrelated lines of changesets.  The first changeset in each line has no parent, but that's not a problem for Mercurial.  Once you pull you'll want to make one new changeset for each line where you `hg mv` everything into the appropriate subfolder, then you merge the lines and you're all set.

Comment: Im about to do the same, I was wondering (since its been some time now since you did this) if you ever encountered any problems using the mega-merged clone?

Comment: I don't remember running into any further problems. But I don't remember which repository I did this on, either :)

Comment: what if the two repositories have code common to both of them. Would that be automatically handled by the merge ? and as for merge, we can ust say $ hg merge ?

Comment: for reference purposes, here is the docs for this process http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MergingUnrelatedRepositories

Answer (score 7):

hg started to have [subrepo](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepositories) since 1.3 (2009-07-01). The early versions were incomplete and shaky but now it's pretty usable.

Comment: I've found subrepos to be a pain to work with. They work but you have to jump through some hoops to get them to behave and can be the source of a lot of headaches if you are not careful.

Comment: Might be worth noting that subrepositories are officially a feature of last resort: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository (as of 2013.11.12)

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't using the same code across the projects, keep them separate. You can set *your* personal repository of each of those projects to be just a directory apart. Why mix all the branches, merges, and commit comments when you don't have to.

**About your edit:** Pushing from One repository to Another. You can always use the [`transplant`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TransplantExtension) command. Although, all this is really side stepping your *desire* to combine the two, so you might feel uncomfortable using my suggestions. Then you can use the forest extension, or something.

```
hg transplant -s REPOSITORY lower_rev:high_rev
```