# Mercurial How To Merge 2 Repositories that share a common ancestor but are not clones of the same repo

Tags: mercurial, hgsubversion

I am using hg-subversion, and I have 2 different hg repositories one from our svn trunk, and one from a branch of the trunk. I would like to link them somehow. At some point in the history both Hg repositories will be identical is there some way to join them?

In other words is there a way to relate the repositories from within Hg?

The technique I am currently using is to just export the second repository over top of the working copy of the revision they share, and then commit that working copy as a branch in Hg, but I lose the history this way.

Any advice would be great

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843/how-to-combine-two-projects-in-mercurial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try importing the two repos into one as if unrelated, then merging them. (When you say they share a common ancestor, do you mean that those ancestors have the same revision ID? If so there is a good chance that this will work well.)

```
hg clone repoA
hg pull -f repoB # may not need -f
hg merge
```

Comment: they have a shared SVN revision ID yeah, since one is actually a branch.

Answer (score 1):

Can you re-clone the Subversion repository, giving the root of the Subversion repository as argument instead of trunk or one of the branches?  I used `hg clone svn+ssh://foo/bar/baz` once, where `svn+ssh://foo/bar/baz/trunk` was the trunk and `svn+ssh://foo/bar/baz/branches/quux` was a branch, and in the end I had two named branches in Mercurial, the "default" branch representing Subversion trunk and the "quux" branch representing the like-named Subversion branch.

If you have outgoing changesets in your existing hg repos, you might be in a bit of a bind there.  If there are just a few outgoing changesets, it might work to enable the `mq` extension and to convert the changesets into patches.  These patches can then be re-applied on the new clone (in the appropriate named branch) and eventually pushed to Subversion.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll definately try them out