# Combination commit history of Mercurial repositories (for Gource)

Tags: mercurial, gource

How to me to combine some repositories that the commit history was adequately displayed in Gource?

[Merging two different repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448788/merging-two-different-repositories) I did everything as is specified there
But in Gource the commits of only one repository is shown

Comment: The `hg log` command shows all the repositories connected ? Better to see with `hg glog --style compact`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a batch file I wrote today that solves the problem for subrepos:

```
REM Remember the directory we started in.
set PreDir=%cd%

REM Clean up old data
DELETE dump.log
DELETE filtereddump.log

REM Generate data for every repo using onsub
hg onsub "gource --output-custom-log test.log"

REM Concatenate all collected data into the one log file
hg onsub "TYPE test.log >> %PreDir%/dump.log"

REM Sort file to get correct chronological order
sort dump.log > filtereddump.log

REM Run gource with the filtered data
gource filtereddump.log
```

Obviously, there are a couple of assumptions here... this is windows specific, subrepository-specific, and relies on the mercurial extension 'onsub' and a sort tool I picked up here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Hope that helped.

PS: This batch script was inspired by info on the Gource wiki. Check out https://code.google.com/p/gource/wiki/GourceMashups