# How to deal with old files in hg repo

Tags: xcode, version-control, mercurial

I have a project I started with Xcode 3.0. Back then source files were stored in the root directory by default. A long time ago I even did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448788/merging-two-different-repositories). Things have evolved, both the project and Xcode and I now have a curious situation:

I have a root folder with the `.xcodeproj` folder used by Xcode and a ton of old source files I will not use again. More recent versions of Xcode have created a similarly named folder where more recent source files exist.

I'd like to clean up my repository. What should I do with the files I am no longer using? Move them to a separate folder? `hg rm`? Checkout the repository anew but from a specific revision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `hg rm`, files will be **moved out of way but kept in the history**. That's the very reason why version control exists. Should you ever need them in the future, checkout a past commit and they will be back.